# css animate rotate svg image 90 degress and stop

Tags: css

How do I animate a image from top left to 90 degress and then stop the animation.

```
.sub-page-logo img {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    
    animation-timing-function: linear;

}
@keyframes spin { 
        from { 
            transform: rotate(0deg); 
        } to { 
            transform: rotate(90deg); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you have should work, what exactly are you having trouble with? (There are a couple of other properties that may help, depending on what you want to achieve, e.g.  [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode), [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that after the animation finishes, the logo jumps back to **0deg**.
You should be able to fix that, if you add: `transform: rotate(90deg);` to your `.sub-page-logo img` like so:

```
.sub-page-logo img{
 ...
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to keep the final state of the animations for your element.

MDN definition (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode):

> The animation-fill-mode CSS property sets how a CSS animation applies styles to its target before and after its execution.

```
.sub-page-logo img {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; //<--- THIS

}
@keyframes spin { 
        from { 
            transform: rotate(0deg); 
        } to { 
            transform: rotate(90deg); 
        }
    }
```